# how to center navigation bar on my website

Tags: html, css

I already checked lots of tutorials but I cant figure out how to center ul list on my website.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- html5.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->    
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagewrap">
    <header id="header">

        <nav>
        <ul id="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test5</a></li>

        </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>   

</div>

</body>
</html>


/* CSS Document */

/*RESET*****************************/
html,body,div,h1,h2,p,img,nav{
margin:0;
padding:0;  
}


body{
background-color:#D1D1D1;
}

#pagewrap{
background-color:#FFF;
width:980px;
margin:60px auto auto;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow:0 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#header{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    height:180px;
}



/*.nav{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:100px;
}*/

#main-nav{
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    border: 2px solid red;
}



#main-nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    float: left;

}

#main-nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 1em;
}
```

this is the code
    http://jsfiddle.net/YS58q/13/

I tried to center it with .nav to but no success. I would appreciate if somebody can suggest maybe better solution the problem. I used relative/absolute positioning. is it possible to do it just with relative positioning. I am planning to do responsive design with media query
thanks a lot :)

Comment: .nav can be called in css only if you have any tag with class 'nav' in your HTML code, like `<div class="nav">` Better you first understand the basics of css selectors, ids, classes etc. [A Simple Tutorial Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is:  http://jsfiddle.net/YS58q/18/

```
nav {
    width: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you :) i dont know the nav component, what is that? is there some other solution ?

Comment: The `nav` is the an html element you've used, just like `div` or `p`, `span`, `table`, `a` etc.  If you wanted to name it with an id you could use: `#myID { width: 1px; margin: 0 auto; }`

You would then need to use: `<nav id="myID">`